# Django Create Multiple URLs that call same View for POST and GET

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I am using URLconfig.  Can I create two URLs (for POST and GET) that call same View?

```
url(r'^persons/(?P<id_person>P\.\d+)/forms/(?P<formacronym>\w+)/$', views.PersonFormView.as_view()),
url(r'^persons/(?P<id_person>P\.\d+)/forms/(?P<id_form>[\w.]+)/$', views.PersonFormView.as_view())
```

Would call these methods in the View respectfully:

```
def get(self, request, id_person, formacronym, format = None):
    form = Form.get_form_for_person(self, id_person, formacronym)

def post(self, request, id_person, id_form, format = None):        
    form = Form.save_form(self, id_person, id_form)
```

The way this is setup now is not working.  Not sure how to proceed.  Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [CBV](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/), you can construct one URL that points to your View. Then depending on the request method the appropriate method on the class will be executed.

```
from django.views.generic import View

class FooView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # only gets called when request.method == "GET"
        assert(request.method == "GET") # True

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # only gets called when request.method == "POST"
        assert(request.method == "POST") # True
```